# Create a scriptableobject file with specific path through code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
CarScriptableObject carScriptableObject = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance < CarScriptableObject > ();
carScriptableObject.numericValues = numericValues;
string carResourcesPath = "Assets/Resources/CarScriptableObject/" + carName + ".asset";
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(carScriptableObject, carResourcesPath);
```

If I use `carName` in `carResourcesPath` receives error[image]

But if I use as a path: `Assets/Resources/CarScriptableObject/A-RS6.asset` everything goes perfectly

I want the name of the cars to be dynamic.

Comment: Maybe in the first one the - is not the normal - but the elongated one. Or just dont have spaces?

Answer (score 0):

This might be just some kind of Anti-Virus or Anti-Malware blocking the file, even Windows Anti-Virus system could be checking the file and thus blocking it.

I wasn't able to reproduce the error (I do not have any kind of 3rd party Anti-Virus or Anti-Malware installed, only Windows protection is enabled). On my side it works fine, and based on some online search, pretty much all pointed to an Anti-Virus or running Unity as Admin.